# Can't work out which index I need for this mysql query - please help?

Tags: mysql, indexing

OK, I can't work out what index I should have on "TBL_PHOTOS" to get this query to run quickly.  Currently taking about 0.8 seconds with 50,000 rows in PH, 50,000 in PL, 300 in R1 and 100 in R2.

If I remove the ORDER BY clause then the query is speedy, taking < 0.05 seconds.

The following is in MySQL by the way:

```
SELECT  PH.tTaken, PH.nPhotoPK, PH.sFilename

FROM TBL_PHOTOS PH
    LEFT JOIN TBL_PHOTO_LINKS PL ON PH.nPhotoPK = PL.nPhotoFK

    LEFT JOIN TBL_RACES1 R1 ON R1.nRacePK = PH.nRace1FK
    LEFT JOIN TBL_RACES2 R2 ON R2.nRacePK = PH.nRace2FK


WHERE PL.nPhotoLinkPK IS NULL

ORDER BY PH.tAdded DESC

LIMIT 0,100
```

The intention is to pull back the 100 most recently uploaded photos that haven't yet been linked to anything. TBL_RACES1 & TBL_RACES2 are two separate tables for a good reason, so I can't change that.  A photo will always belong to one entity from R1 *or* R2, never both.

Apologies if that's bad SQL for some reason, it's not my strong point.  I'm not even sure what information you will need to help me out, so if I've left something vital out just ask.

I have a few indexes set on the table already, but in an explain statement I get

```
possible_keys: (Null)
key: (null)
ref: (null)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If removing the ORDER BY makes the query run a lot faster, then the problem is in the sorting. You are likely extracting thousands of rows and then taking the top 100.  Restructure the query so you extract the most recent 100 photos first, then join to the other tables.  Something like this (untested):

```
SELECT  tTaken, nPhotoPK, sFilename
FROM 
    (select * from TBL_PHOTOS order by tAdded DESC LIMIT 0,100) PH
    LEFT JOIN TBL_PHOTO_LINKS PL ON PH.nPhotoPK = PL.nPhotoFK
    LEFT JOIN TBL_RACES1 R1 ON R1.nRacePK = PH.nRace1FK
    LEFT JOIN TBL_RACES2 R2 ON R2.nRacePK = PH.nRace2FK
WHERE PL.nPhotoLinkPK IS NULL
```

I'm not up on MySQL syntax to be sure this is the way to express it in MySQL, but this should give you the general idea.

Comment: Thank you, changing it to:


SELECT Q.tTaken, Q.nPhotoPK, Q.sFilename FROM

(SELECT PH.tTaken, PH.nPhotoPK, PH.sFilename, PH.nRace1FK, PH.nRace2FK
 FROM TBL_PHOTOS PH
  LEFT JOIN TBL_PHOTO_LINKS PL ON PH.nPhotoPK = PL.nPhotoFK
 WHERE PL.nPhotoLinkPK IS NULL
  ORDER BY PH.nPhotoPK DESC
 LIMIT 0,60) Q

LEFT JOIN TBL_RACES R1 ON R1.nRacePK = Q.nRace1FK
LEFT JOIN TBL_RACES R2 ON R2.nRacePK = Q.nRace2FK

seems to have done the trick.  Is that the sort of thing you meant?

Comment: Am I missing something here, can't figure out how to paste/format code

 in
 this
 comments box!

Comment: OK, that didn't work entirely, as I had slimmed down the query I was asking about.  The bigger problem was that I had "ORDER BY col1 ASC, col2 DESC".  I now know that MySQL *cannot cope* with such things, and I've had to create a "reverse" column to get around it.  Rubbish!

Comment: you can post inline code `like this` in the comment box but not blocks of code. if you need to post extensive code in response to an answer the best thing to do is often to edit your question.